# FPT algorithm for Knapsack

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, knapsack-problems, parameterized-complexity

I tried to search whether Knapsack (the decision version) has a FPT algorithm, but didn't find anything on the topic.
Can someone help with a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference you should have found is [1], where the authors consider several parameters and also higher dimensional knapsack problems (see e.g., Table 1 for a list of running times for different parameters). A non-paywalled [version is on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07724.pdf).

---

[1] [Gurski, Frank, Carolin Rehs, and Jochen Rethmann. "Knapsack problems: A parameterized point of view." Theoretical Computer Science 775 (2019): 93-108.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304397518307527)

Comment: Is there any parameter of the KP problem that we know that the class is not in FPT (not PFPT)? I mean, a parameter that, when considering it, KP is at least W[1]-hard.

Comment: @JoshHalas According to the paper, the answer is yes if you consider the multidimensional variant of the problem. But if you insist on KP, the paper doesn't seem to give any such results. I also don't know of any such results.